# Codename one how to place an icon on top of the border-top container

Tags: containers, codenameone

codename one how to place an icon on top of the  border-top container as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a part of the Input demo in the kitchen sink demo: https://www.codenameone.com/demos-KitchenSink.html

The code is here: https://github.com/codenameone/KitchenSink/blob/master/src/com/codename1/demos/kitchen/Input.java#L167

It's actually pretty simple:

```
Container actualContent = LayeredLayout.encloseIn(content, 
                    FlowLayout.encloseCenter(avatar));
```

We place the avatar in the top of the content container in a layered layout. Then we set the UIID of content to something else and use margin to space it down a bit so the line of the border passes lower.

So if contents margin top is equal to half the height of the avatar the border line will pass in the middle.